# (Blazor WASM) Getting RouteData in service

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a simple app I'm building something like a state service that pulls data from the server fully driven by navigation. This forces me to have proper working routes for every state of the app and keeps my implementation clean and simple.

Core thing in my service is of course to subscribe to `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` and change the state accordingly. But although `NavigationManager.Uri` has everything I need, I lack the parsing of route variables that `Router` provides via `RouteData` and is available as `CascadingParameter` in pages and components.

How can I access the current `RouteData` whenever I handle the `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` in my service? Or how can I do this differently (react to navigation changes and change my service state accordingly)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a component to handle passing RouteData to your service:

```
public class RouteDataHandler : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "AppRouteData")] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteData? routeData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Pass it to a service
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

Add the cascade to `App.razor`:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Name="AppRouteData" Value="@routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        <RouteDataHandler />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: [Polite] Your solution won't work. The `RouteDataHandler` component will be rendered only once, when the `Router` is rendered for the first time, and the service to which the route data is passed will always have the same route data, for the Index component. You shouldn't do that like that.

Comment: Thanks.  Spotted my "deliberate" (stupid) error.  Updated to trigger on `OnParametersSet` now.